# SQL make time in datetime 12pm

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `datetime` field as

```
03/04/2016 08:00:00 AM
03/15/2016 04:00:00 AM
```

I want to keep it as `datetime` but set the time to 12am for all entries. So the result should be

```
03/04/2016 12:00:00 AM
03/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

No tsql or declaring variables.

Comment: what do you mean "no t-sql"?

Comment: Your subject line says pm but the text of the question says am.  Please clarify.

Comment: 12:00:00 is PM. 12 AM is midnight and is 00:00:00 as a datetime.

Comment: Title says 12PM, question says 12AM. I suspect it's a duplicate of "I just want the date part"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Comment: Here is a list of different techniques you could use to manipulate the time. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/202288/16391). If by "no tsql or declaring variables", you mean you want the table to take care of this, you can create a Trigger to address the data before (or immediately after) its put away into the row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DATEADD(hour, 12, CAST(CAST(myfield AS Date) AS Datetime))
```

Comment: I'm conflicted about upvoting this. I mean, it does what op wants, but I'm still unsure what does the `No t-sql` requirement means

Comment: I take that as meaning something that doesn't work within a single `select`.