# DateDiff into Hours and have decimals

Tags: sql, type-conversion, datediff

I have two times periods from the same day and I am using `datediff(Hour,FirstTime,SecondTime)*1.0` to get the hours difference, but it is rounding. I am expecting 4.5 but my results keep coming back as 5.0

I tried casting each time, formatting each time before datediff but the results are the same. I know I am missing a simple solution probably because I am too close to the issue.

Comment: `Hour` is integer, if you want decimals you have to calculate it yourself from `Minute`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? datediff is a product specific function.

Comment: If using MSSQL this may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/202288/16391.  DateDiff is only going to return Counts not Results